# Angular Universal page doesn't update until mouse event

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-universal

I've ported an Angular 5 app over to Angular Universal and I'm seeing odd behaviour. My pages are rendering fine, but only after some sort of mouse action. For example, the page loads (I assume just the server-side version), and then when I mouse over a menu item, the page instantly updates to show the actual updated page with content.

I tried adding a manual change detection update (see below) just to see if it would help. It did not.

```
constructor(... , private changeRef: ChangeDetectorRef ) {}

// after calling my web service to get content (browser side)
this.changeRef.detectChanges();
```

Here's my main.ts file:

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

Comment: What's the content of your main.ts file?

Comment: Main.ts: import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);

Comment: Does it change anything if you repalce the last line with document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
});

Comment: @David no, that didn't help, but thanks for trying. The only thing I've found to help is calling this.changeRef.detectChanges(); after making changes on the browser-side. It seems very un-Angular. There must be a better way

Answer (score 0):

The solution seems to be to use NgZone.run().

```
import { NgZone, } from '@angular/core';

...
constructor( private _ngZone: NgZone ) {}
...

this._ngZone.run(() => {
  // code that calls the REST API here
});
```